# Python: serializing/deserializing datetime.time

Tags: python, datetime

I have a form with  dropdowns full of times, represented with datetime.time objects.

What's the best way to serialize the object?  eg:

```
<option value="${time.serialize()}">${time.isoformat()}</option>
```

And then deserialize it on the other end? eg:

```
time = datetime.time.deserialize(request.params['time'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3.6 and newer you can use the [`datetime.time.isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.isoformat) function to serialize and in Python 3.7 and newer you can use the [`datetime.time.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.fromisoformat) function to deserialize. So it would look like this

```py
import datetime
time_string = datetime.datetime.now().time().isoformat()
time_obj = datetime.time.fromisoformat(time_string)
```

and to do this with a `datetime` instead of a `time`, it would look like

```py
import datetime
datetime_string = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(datetime_string)
```

Answer (score 11):

If you `repr` a `datetime.time` object, Python gives you `isoformat`. As `repr`s attempt to be serialized versions of their objects, that's a good indication it's the value you should use.

```
import datetime

timestring = datetime.datetime.now().time().isoformat()

timeobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
```